# retrieving google blog data with given url or userID programmatically (C#)

Tags: c#, google-api, blogger

I am creating a c# console app, which will retrieve the data from all the blogs of a particular User by using a UserID & Password.

So that i found the code below--->

```
using Google.GData.Blogger;
using Google.GData.Client;

namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Service service = new Service("blogger", "blogger-example");

            // ClientLogin using username/password authentication
            string username;
            string password;
            if (args.Length != 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Usage: BloggerDevSample.exe <username> <password>");
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                username = args[0];
                password = args[1];
            }

            service.Credentials = new GDataCredentials(username, password);

            ListUserBlogs(service);

            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to quit");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void ListUserBlogs(Service service)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nRetrieving a list of blogs");
            FeedQuery query = new FeedQuery();
            // Retrieving a list of blogs   
            query.Uri = new Uri("http://www.blogger.com/feeds/default/blogs");
            AtomFeed feed = null;
            feed = service.Query(query);
            foreach (AtomEntry entry in feed.Entries)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("  Blog title: " + entry.Title.Text);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It currently getting the data with username & password, which shuld be known,
But i want **to get the blog data using a URL of a particular blog, thus any blog data could be accessed without having the private credentials(username & password**) only with tha blog URL.
I think this can be achieved with some APIs provided by Goggle, but how ???

Comment: @Kiquenet; @Rakhitha; But i got UnAuthorized Exception...

Answer (score 0):

How about reading the blogs RSS feed?

Comment: ::dont understand...
can u explain it or give me a link to get more abt RSS feed ?

Comment: RSS is used by most blogs to expose the content of the sites. They basically follow a simple XML format. Basically every blog publish a RSS url which exposes it posts. Anyone can read it as it is public. Only problem is that a blog may choose to publish only the most recent posts through it. If you want to read all the posts then this will not work. Here is a link to RSS introduction http://www.w3schools.com/Rss/rss_intro.asp.